# MySQL - group by like classification

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table :

```
/* Create a table called users */
CREATE TABLE users(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, country text);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO users VALUES(1,'Tom','Canada');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(2,'Lucy','USA');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(3,'Frank','USA');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(4,'Jane','Canada');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(5,'Robert','Italy');
COMMIT;
```

I want a query that displat this result :

```
+---+--------+--------+
| 1 |  Tom   | Canada |
+---+--------+--------+
| 4 | Jane   | Canada |
| 3 | Frank  | USA    |
| 2 | Lucy   | USA    |
| 5 | Robert | Italy  |
+---+--------+--------+
```

that mean classification users by countries. For that I use this query :

```
SELECT * FROM users group by country;
```

but the result is not satisfying, because the `group by` delete duplicate rows.

Any advice will be nice.

Comment: Can you give slightly more details? You're requesting a specific `ORDER`, not a `GROUP BY`.  But, why does `Italy` sort last? Do you intend these to be ordered alphabetically, or by the count of values?

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output looks more like a specific ordering than a grouping. For ordering use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY country;
```